# How to run a query in JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I've the below query in my SQLServer.

```sql
update time_tracker
set logout = '08-11-2016 17:28:02', totaltime = DATEDIFF(minute,login, logout) 
from Time_Tracker 
where userid = 0138039 AND CONVERT(Date, LOGIN) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
```

And in my JDBC I'm taking the below query

```
    Date endDate = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String logoutTime = dateFormat.format(endDate);
    System.out.println(logoutTime);

    String sql = 
        "update time_tracker " + 
        "set logout = ?, totaltime = DATEDIFF(minute,login, logout) " +
        "from Time_Tracker " +
        "where userid= ? AND CONVERT(Date, LOGIN) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())";

    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, logoutTime);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, userId);
    preparedStatement.execute();
    preparedStatement.close();
```

When I run this program, there is no update done in my backend, But when I run the query directly in my SQL Server, it is working fine. Please let me know where Am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you commit on ur connection? If auto commit is not on, then this could be a reason.

Comment: How are you handling transactions? Are you doing a commit explicitly, or do you have automatic commits enabled?

Comment: What is the type of logout?

Comment: what's the ` from Time_Tracker ` part doing in this query?!?

Comment: logout is a varchar or a datetime?

Comment: Doesn't look like valid SQL to me.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, it is of Datetime

Comment: @Jesper, Rishigoel, I've a conn.commit() followed by a conn.close().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think U can change follow:
*preparedStatement.executeUpdate();*

Comment: Thanks friend, this worked :)

Comment: You are welcome friend